# PHP Version 5.3.24 Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_dir_writeable()

Tags: php, magento

My hosting provider just upgraded php to PHP Version 5.3.24 and it was working for a day then suddenly i started getting this fatal error on my magento hosting.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_dir_writeable() in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 220

And then later not just in magento but it is default error in very basic php file. Can anyone help me to find a direction on what might happened here.

Comment: looks like your hosting company is changing settings

Answer (score 0):

is_dir_writable() seems to be a Magento specific function and should be located in Mage/Core/functions.php

See here:
http://www.magentodocs.org/1.5.1.0/d2/d62/functions_8php.php#a79b0ab7072a0afd5a074760a361e1894

Is that file still available and is the function still there?

Comment: Yes Thanks for pointing, the functions.php file is present in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php but still am getting this error.

Comment: Try adding: require_once("/path/to/magento/Mage/Core/functions.php") to the top of the file that triggers this error (just to be sure) (And yes, try the cleanup tool SaveTheMage suggests)